# glTranslatef not working within glBegin .. glEnd

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw 2 squares side by side of different colours, my problem is I can't get glTranslatef to move my second square to the right, the second square just draws over the first.

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPointSize(10);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
        drawSquare();

        glTranslatef(10,0,0);

        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        drawSquare();

    glEnd();    

    glFlush();  // Process all OpenGL routines
}

void drawSquare()
{
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(10,0,0);
    glVertex3f(10,10,0);
    glVertex3f(0,10,0);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot translate inside a `glBegin/glEnd` block, you have break it up into two blocks.

I recommend to start using `glGetError()` in your code, it will help you find mistakes like this.

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer worked for me perfectly. Is there anything you'd recommend I'd read online for starting off openGL?

Answer (score 7):

Only a certain subset of OpenGL commands is allowed between glBegin and glEnd. So, when you call glTranslate between those two calls, it is ignored.

Remove glBegin and glEnd from display, and put in drawSquare - that should work.

Comment: Not only will it be ignores, it actually triggers the GL_INVALID_OPERATION error flag.